# Group by multiple columns and count results

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I group by multiple columns, and return the overall results as count with ActiveRecord (Rails 3) and MySql? I tried it with

```
MyModel.count(group: [:col1, :col2])
```

but this returns a big hash (there are about 75.000 records in the table), and I only need the overall row count that this query returns.

I could do

```
MyModel.count(group: [:col1, :col2]).count # => 5266
```

but this would load all the stuff into Rails, which gets slow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
MyModel.group(:col1).group(:col2).count
```

I noticed this doesnt work with association fields, but works fine with their id columns.

Comment: Yes, gives same result, as `MyModel.count(group: [:col1, :col2])`

Comment: You want the number of unique pairs of `[:col1, :col2]`? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Exactly! I have a list where I write the grouped result of `col1` and `col2`, and for pagination, I need the overall count of all rows

Comment: Hmm.. not too sure then.. is this something that might be done in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct count of each field like this.

```
MyModel.pluck('COUNT(DISTINCT col1) as col1, COUNT(DISTINCT col2) as col2')
```

And you receive a result like this

```
[[13273, 0]]
```